# Checking if a JavaScript setTimeout has fired

Tags: javascript, queue, settimeout

I'd like to be able to dispatch a bunch of work via JavaScript to be done in the browser in such a way that the browser stays responsive throughout.

The approach I'm trying to take is to chunk up the work, passing each chunk to a function that is then queued with a `setTimeout(func, 0)` call.

I need to know when all the work is done, so I'm storing the returned timer ID in a map (id -> true|false). This mapping is set to false in the next block of code after I have the timer ID, and the queued function sets the mapping to true when it completes... except, of course, the queued function doesn't know its timer ID.

Maybe there's a better/easier way... or some advice on how I can manipulate my map as I need to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would queue the work in an array, use one timeout to process the queue and call a callback once the queue is empty. Something like:

```
var work = [...];

var run = function(work, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(work.length > 0) {
            process(work.shift());
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }
    }, 25);
};

run(work, function() {
    alert('Work is done!');
});
```

As JavaScript in browsers is single threaded there is no real advantage to run multiple timeouts (at least I think this is what you are doing). It may even slow down the browser.

Comment: OK, so I think the main different being that this approach recursively sets timeouts on the next work item as the current one completes, instead of setting timeouts on all the items up front and checking for completion. I can give it a try... cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that although javascript is single threaded you can still have multiple ajax calls going at once.  I recently had a site that needed to do potentially hundreds of ajax calls and the browser just couldn't handle it.  I created a queue that used setTimeOut to run 5 calls at once.  When one of the ajax calls returned it fired a callback (which is handled by a single thread) and then made the next call on the stack.

Imagine you're a manager that can only talk to one person at a time, you give 5 employees assignments, then wait for their responses, which may come in any order.  Once the first employee comes back and gives you the information, you give them a new assignment and wait for the next employee (or perhaps even the same employee) to come back.  So although you're "single threaded" 5 things are going on at once.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example right in the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html), how it is best to handle it:

> To run tasks of several milliseconds back to back without any delay,
>   while still yielding back to the browser to avoid starving the user
>   interface (and to avoid the browser killing the script for hogging the
>   CPU), simply queue the next timer before performing work:
>
> ```
> function doExpensiveWork() {
>   var done = false;
>   // ...
>   // this part of the function takes up to five milliseconds
>   // set done to true if we're done
>   // ...
>   return done;
> }
>
> function rescheduleWork() {
>   var handle = setTimeout(rescheduleWork, 0); // preschedule next iteration
>   if (doExpensiveWork())
>     clearTimeout(handle); // clear the timeout if we don't need it
> }
>
> function scheduleWork() {
>   setTimeout(rescheduleWork, 0);
> }
>
> scheduleWork(); // queues a task to do lots of work
> ```

The moment of finishing the work is pretty clear, when `clearTimeout` is called.