# Add milliseconds to timeout

Tags: javascript

I've create a timeout in JavaScript that looks like this:

```
var milliseconds = 3000;
var timer = setTimeout(function() { console.log('done!'); }, milliseconds);
```

This timer runs for 3 seconds. However, sometimes, I want to add an additional minute. My challenge is, sometimes, the timer has already started. For example, the timer may have one minute and 45 seconds left before the function is called. However, I want to add a minute such that the timeout function is called in two minutes and 45 seconds.

Is there a way to add milliseconds to a timeout in JavaScript. I don't see a function that allows this.

Comment: No, there's no way to add time to a timeout that is already executing. You'd have to cancel the timeout and run a new one with the time left plus the added time.

Comment: Actually that timer's delay is 3 seconds

Comment: this could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844993/checking-if-a-javascript-settimeout-has-fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Timer {
 constructor(func){
   this.func = func;
   this.timers = [];
 }
 start(time){
   setTimeout(_=>this.check(),time);
 }
 add(time){
   this.timers.push(time);
 }
 check(){
   if(!this.timers.length) return this.func();
   this.start(this.timers.shift());
 }
}
```

Usable like this:

```
var t = new Timer(_=>alert("hi"));
t.start(1000);
t.add(3000);
```

Basically this implements a timers queue. Adding an amount of time does not change the timer, but adds the time onto the queue. If a timer finished, it only executes the function if there are no timers left, if theres one it proceeds with it.